# How to relay broadcast traffic using ncat?

Tags: linux, routing, kali-linux, port-forwarding

I have 2 servers, 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1. I want to relay any broadcast traffic (192.168.2.255) through 192.168.2.1 to 192.168.1.1.

Here's what I'm doing to relay port 137 traffic, and it seems to work fine.

*on 192.168.2.1*

```
echo ncat.exe 192.168.1.1 1337 > relay.bat
ncat.exe -l -p 137 -e relay.bat
```

*on 192.168.1.1*

```
nc -lnvp 192.168.1.1 1337
```

I can only find how to forward ports with ncat. I can't bind to 192.168.2.255 to listen of course. 
I hope that makes sense what I'm trying to do.

Comment: netcat requires a port to listen on and is probably not what you want. You are probably looking for a relay, such as a dhcp relay, or a bridge. What type of broadcast traffic are you hoping to bridge?

Comment: I want to relay NBNS protocol traffic that is sent on port 137. I'm conducting a penetration test in a lab, and want to conduct an NBNS spoof attack.

Comment: I think I'm gonna close this one and open a new one, removing ncat from the equation.